# Perform foreach only on specific array

Tags: php, foreach

I want to perform  a `foreach`-operation on a specific array. I have an array like this:

```
$a=array("car"=>array("car1","car2","car3"),"plane"=>array("plane1","plane2","plane3"));
```

How can I be able to perform a `foreach` only on the array that is named `car` (i.e., excluding `plane`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to show the car array using foreach

```
foreach($a["car"] as $c) { 
echo $c;
}
```